# How can I set encryption password, when making a backup with TWRP via ADB?

Tags: adb, backup, twrp

It is not about decryption, like others have already asked.

I need to know how to set encryption key, via CLI.

`adb backup --twrp` then what?

Will it use my phone's encryption password?
If so, why won't it ask me for a different password like the GUI does?

Comment: The adb backup for twrp works differently than adb backup that works when Android is running. TWRP doesn't support encryption of backups. Well, it is not at least mentioned here: https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html